# JS нули перед числом

Tags: javascript

Как можно указать размер выводимого числа (двоичного) ?

пробовал так

```
      function PrefInt(number, len) {
         if (number.length < len)
         {
            alert(number.length);
            return (Array(len).join('0') + number).slice(-length);
         }

      error.innerHTML = PrefInt((parseInt(bufvalue, 10).toString(2)), 7);
```

для 17 получил 00000010001 (на 3 нуля больше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы почти всё верно написали только ошиблись в одном месте:

```
  function PrefInt(number, len) {
     if (number.length < len)
     {
        alert(number.length);
        return (Array(len).join('0') + number).slice(-len); // тут было у вас lenght которое не определено поэтому и возвращалось число без обрезания
     }
  } // тут функция не закрыта ещё
  error.innerHTML = PrefInt((parseInt(bufvalue, 10).toString(2)), 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

а понял

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

error.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(bufvalue, 10).toString(2), 8);
```

Comment: Тоже вариант _)